# Placing Google maps pins with PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I am trying to print out markers via PHP and Javascript. The below code DOES work. I am basically printing out each new marker. However, I feel that this isn't very efficient or optimal way to do it.

I read mentioned on another Stack thread that a better way might be to create a PHP array and then convert that to a javascript array via js_encode. Then use that to output the markers. Some guidance on how to do this would be great, or a more efficient way to do what I am trying to do? Thanks.

```
<?php

global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'my_places' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
            $pin_location = get_field('my_map');
            $pin_latitude   = $pin_location['lat'];
            $pin_longitude  = $pin_location['lng'];
            $pin_title = get_the_title();
            $pin_content = get_the_content();
?>
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: <?php echo $pin_latitude; ?>, lng: <?php echo $pin_longitude; ?>},
          map: map,
          title: 'Pin Title'
        });

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be it's help to you HTML demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MansukhKhandhar/bhgq5m02/)

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'my_places' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
            $pin_location = get_field('my_map');
            $pin_latitude   = $pin_location['lat'];
            $pin_longitude  = $pin_location['lng'];
            $pin_title = get_the_title();
            $pin_content = get_the_content();
            $pin_icon    = 'https://www.prudential.com.sg/export/system/modules/com.prudential.template/resources/images/MainNavigation/Map_small_icon.png';

?>
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: <?php echo $pin_latitude; ?>, lng: <?php echo $pin_longitude; ?>},
          map: map,
          title: 'Pin Title',
          icon: <?php echo  $pin_icon;?>
        });

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```